# global variable that returns a true or false

Tags: objective-c

can anyone show me how to implement a var that displays a true value on user input and this value can be used in other controllers to add a value to a different controller...
i would like to use this code to signal arrays to add objects. If anyone has a better way to implement this I would appreciate that too.

I have an ibaction that requires a uibutton to be clicked.
When this button is clicked i want a variable to be triggered.
add favorites lets say.

When this variable is triggered i want to go to another controller
and say if variable = true add this object to the array.

Comment: Most likely you'll have to expand upon your problem in more detail before you get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the changes in a property to trigger things to happen in other objects I think [Key-Value Observation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) is what you need.  Or you couild just call a method on your other controller from the action.